# how to convert a one dimensional table to a dataframe with two columns

Tags: r

OK so this may represent my ignorance about tables to dataframes. I have a table as called tbb which is made up of stuff from a dataframe called mydata.
I then do some summary stats using colsums and I would them like to convert the colsums back to a dataframe. However when I do this it only seems to recognise one of the two columns as a column:

This is the result of my colsums

```
LSU-rRNA_Hsa     LTR1          LTR10A          LTR10B         LTR10B1 
     309          90             351             404             183
  LTR10C       LTR10D          LTR10E          LTR10F          LTR10G 
   181           675             173              72             231              
 LTR12          LTR12          LTR12B          LTR12C          
   333            359              15             144   


 But when I then convert this to a dataframe I get 


 LSU-rRNA_Hsa      181
 LTR1              675
 LTR10A            173
 LTR10B             72
 LTR10B1           231
 LTR10C            309
 LTR10D             90
 LTR10E            351
 LTR10F            404
 LTR10G            183
 LTR12             379
 LTR12_            273
 LTR12B             86
 LTR12C            497
```

Great. Until I do ncol and it tells me I only have one column which is the numbers, not the LTR etc. Why is this and what am I doing wrong in the conversion? Here's the code:

```
 mydata = read.table("/Users/Repeats.txt")
 #General tidy up
 mydata[4:6] <- NULL
 mydata[5] <- NULL
 names(mydata) <- c("chrom", "chromStart", "chromEnd","Rptname")
 tbb <- table(mydata$chromStart,mydata$Rptname)
 tbb[tbb == 0] <- NA
 tbb[tbb > 0] <- 1
 coll <- as.data.frame(colSums(tbb,na.rm = TRUE))
```

Comment: These are probably just your row names. You can extract and save them at will. Try `row.names(coll)`.

Comment: Ah yes they are row names. So the end aim is to plot the number against the row name. The dataframe calls the one column colSums(tbb, na.rm = TRUE). So when I try to create the plot with names((colSums(tbb, na.rm = TRUE))) <- c("mycol") + plot(mycol) there is no x-axis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The names are converted into rownames. You can do the following instead:

```
result = colSums(tbb, na.rm = TRUE)
result = data.frame(Names = names(result), Values = result)
```